# How do ES6 tagged template functions interpret their argument order?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

Consider the following code:

```
function f() {
  console.log(Array.from(arguments));
}

var x = 2;
var y = 3;
f`before ${x} ${y} after`;
```

The arguments for `f` would be ([according to Traceur](http://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#function%20f()%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(Array.from(arguments))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20x%20%3D%202%3B%0Avar%20y%20%3D%203%3B%0Af%60before%20%24%7Bx%7D%20%24%7By%7D%20after%60%3B)):

```
["before ", " ", " after"], 2, 3
```

Let's say I want to concatenate all literal strings with substitution values.
How do I do that in the correct order?

Do I need to match 'split points' in the first array with each argument after first?

Comment: Looks like it. If you look at the AST, the template string is "divided" into three quasis and two expressions (at least esprima does that). Humble self promotion: http://felix-kling.de/esprima_ast_explorer/ lets you inspect the AST.

Comment: Isn't that just what the [default quasi tag](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:quasis#default_quasi_tag) already does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wiki for the Draft ECMAScript 6 Specification, it is more complicated because templates take escape sequences into account:

The template

> ```
> quasiTag`literalPortion\0 $x literalPortion1`
> ```

will desugar to

> ```
> // Declaration hoisted to top of module.
> // Escape sequences in the hoisted declaration are not decoded according to CV(EscapeSequence).
> // The calls to Object.freeze use the original definition of that method.
> const unguessableCallSiteId1234 = Object.freeze({
>   raw: Object.freeze(["literalPortion\\0 ", "literalPortion1"]),
>   cooked: Object.freeze(["literalPortion\u0000 ", "literalPortion1"])
> });
>
> ...
>
>   // In-situ
>   // Escape sequences in the arguments are decoded.
>   // unguessableCallSiteId1234 is ideal as a key into a weak map used to memoize
>   // extraction of meta-data, custom escaping conventions, and other state
>   // that can be derived from the literal portions, so does not vary from
>   // call to call from the same call-site.
>   quasiTag(unguessableCallSiteId1234, x)
> ```
>
> [*EcmaScript Quasi-Literals - Desugaring*](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:quasis#desugaring)

So `arguments` should contain the substitution values as you see with traceur but the literal portions are an object and not an array.

If you want to implement it for code compiled with traceur you could do something like in the following unoptimized example.

```
let concatenated = "";
Array.forEach(args[0], (e, i) =>
    concatenated += e + ( i < arguments.length - 1 ? arguments[i+1] : "")
);
```

For real ECMAScript 6 code take a look at the [Default Quasi Tag](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:quasis#default_quasi_tag) implementation, as bergi suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! Is that the latest version? Currently I see three versions: 1) draft spec definition (object with `raw`/`cooked`), 2) draft spec default quasi tag (uses some property called `expandedLP`), and 3) traceur implementation ('cooked' array with `raw` as a property). Is raw/cooked object (1) the final one?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin The latest draft I can find is from 2014-07-18 http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts. In _12.2.9 Template Literals_ they use the raw/cooked object (1) variant. It looks like they have dropped the name _quasi literals_ and renamed the whole thing to _template literals_. It's still a draft so no one can say for sure if it will be the final version.

Answer (score 3):

There's always one more literal portion than substitution. The first literal is the first part of the template (or empty string if it starts with a substitution), and the last literal is the tail of the template string (or, again, an empty string if it ends with a substitution).

To get the parts in order, access `literal[0]`, `sub[0]`, `literal[1]`, ..., `sub[sub.length-1]`, `literal[sub.length]`.

Here's a simple starting point:

```
function simpleTag(lit, ...sub) {
  return sub.reduce(
    // Add next substition and following literal
    (soFar, s, i) => soFar + s + lit[i+1],
    lit[0] // Start with the first literal
  );
}
```