# Difference (if there is any) between ` and ' in javascript

Tags: javascript, apostrophe

Recently ran into some JS code that uses `` ` `` and `'`. I can't figure out if there is a different use for each apostrophe. Is there any?

Comment: ` is not an apostrophe. It is a grave accent mark.

Comment: See template strings https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Do you mean template strings  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660381/backticks-calling-a-function)

Comment: Yup, template strings, that's it for `\``.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`'` or `"` denotes a *string*

`` ` `` denotes a *template string*. Template strings have some abilities that normal strings do not. Most importantly, you get interpolation:

```
var value = 123;
console.log('test ${value}') //=> test ${value}
console.log(`test ${value}`) //=> test 123
```

And multiline strings:

```
console.log('test
test')
// Syntax error

console.log(`test
test`)
// test
// test
```

They have some other tricks too, more on template strings here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Babel solved the back tick problem in IE11 for me: