# I want to pass dynamically changing value to react Link react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to set navigate to a different route when below link clicked.

```
<Link to={'/q/${item.qID}'} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>{item.qContent}</Link>
```

The real result is

```
http://localhost:3000/q/$%7Bitem.qID%7D
```

Expected results is

```
http://localhost:3000/q/122
```

(122 = item.qID)

Comment: Possible typo(?). Should be a backtick (`\``) for string template, i.e. `to={\`/q/${item.qID}\`}`.

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is wrong, in order to use a dynamic string you have to wrap your string inside backtick character(`).

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679732/difference-if-there-is-any-between-and-in-javascript)