# Need explanation on following type of Javascript code

Tags: javascript, syntax

I use codefights and one of the solutions for finding if a string is palindrome or not is as follows:

```
PalindromeOrNot = s =>
s == [...s].reverse().join`` ? `Yes` : `No`
```

Here PalindromeOrNot is the function name and s is a parameter. I understand that the second line directly returns Yes or No but there is no return keyword used. Also, I have never seen such code anywhere else in Javascript. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's deconstruct this:

```
PalindromeOrNot =    // an assignment
s => stmt            // arrow notation, shorthand(*) for function (s) { return stmt; }
s ==                 // ...where "stmt" is: a comparison
[...s]               // array destructuring (turns s into an array of characters)
.reverse().join``    // reverse the array, join with the empty string
?                    // ternary operator (after the comparison)
`Yes` : `No`         // results of the ternary, either 'Yes' or 'No',
                     // depending on whether the string equals its reverse
```

So in other words, this is a fancy way of writing

```
PalindromeOrNot = function (s) {
    return s == s.split('').reverse().join('') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

On ``` .join`` ``` read this question: [Backticks calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660381/backticks-calling-a-function)

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Almost. There is a difference between the regular functions and array functions when it comes to the handling of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be equivalent to this function:

```
PalindromeOrNot = function (s) {
  return s == s.split('').reverse().join('') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

It just have some ES2015 sugar syntax like [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `(params) => expression`, [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `[...variable]` and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `` `string text` ``.