# semicolon needed after an assignment followed by js string interpolation

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment followed by a string interpolation:

```
var a = 3;
`${a} One two three`

"3 One two three"
```

If I leave ou the ; after the assignment then the code becomes invalid:

```
var a = 3
`${a} One two three`

VM573:2 Uncaught TypeError: 3 is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:1
```

I thought that ; is mandatory only after {}...
Can somebody explain the above please?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: [Backticks calling a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660381/backticks-calling-a-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `3` is being interpreted as a [template literal tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals). A template literal can be preceded with a "tag" which is a reference to a function. For example:

```
function tag() {
  return 'other string';
}
const s = tag`some string`;
console.log(s); // 'other string'
```

In your case, an error is thrown because `3` is not a function. The semicolon disambiguates the number and causes it to be parsed as exactly that - a number.