# how to write an array mixer with ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Currently learning ES 6 & 7, i wrote a function to mix an array and i wanted to train by "translating" this function to es 6, it seems to not work and i don't find my mistake, can anyone help me ?

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var mixer = array => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let randomized = Math.round(Math.random() * array.length)
        [array[randomized], array[i]] = [array[i], array[randomized]]
    }
    return array
}

mixer(arr)
```

here's the error i receive from google chrome

> Uncaught ReferenceError: randomized is not defined
>       at mixer (prog.js:6)
>       at prog.js:11

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Define what exactly a "mixer" does, please? Is that a *shuffle*?

Comment: Thank you very much Weedoze, i just realise the function isn't working as i expected, sometimes it's telling me undefined like this [1, 4, 2, undefined, undefined, 3, 5] can you help me on this ? edit : yes that's right deceze it's a shuffle, maybe there's already a method to mix an array but i wanted to make a function for it for practicing

Comment: @A.S check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

## Problem A : `randomized is not defined`

You forgot the `;`'s at the end of the lines

## Problem B : `undefined` values

Start iterating by the end of the array

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var mixer = array => {
    for (let i = array.length; i; i--) {
        let randomized = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [array[i - 1], array[randomized]] = [array[randomized], array[i - 1]];
    }
    return array;//here
}

console.log(mixer(arr))
```

Comment: You're on it today! Close as simple typo?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Perhaps it is not a type. OP may think that `;` are not necessary inside es6 function

Comment: Just a heads up: this still can add `undefined` to your array.

Comment: @user3297291 The first problem was solved with adding `:`. The thing with undefined is another problem

Comment: I know it's another problem and I think your answer was very on-topic; I just wanted to warn people doing the "copy-paste-stackoverflow-thing" expecting to get a working shuffle function ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

***TL;DR***: Whenever you start a line with `(` or `[` make sure to end the previous instruction with a semicolon if possible.

I just want to add to Weedoze's answer.
You actually only really need the first semicolon that he suggested.
This can be confusing because semicolons are optional 99% of the time.
It can help a lot to ask yourself what your code would look like if you would put it into one line. Especially when you start a line with `(` or `[`. And as Bergi suggested in the comments, also watch out for lines starting with `/`, `+`, `-` and `` ` `` .

For instance take this code:

```
test = 123
a = test
(b = 456)
```

It will throw an error saying something like `test is not a function`. Why? Well, because

```
a = test
(b = 456)
```

is equal to

```
a = test(b = 456)
```

If you would have written

```
test = 123
a = test;
(b = 456)
```

then your code would have been clear and still have the same meaning, even if you put line 2 and 3 on the same line:

```
a = test;(b = 456)
```

Comment: Thank you i understand i knew about the semicolon but from the person i learned javascript, he was never using semicolon so i got the reflex to not use it either and now i see again how important it is

Comment: `(` and `[`? Or `/`, `+`, `-` and `\``!

Comment: @Bergi True. I never found myself in a situation where I found myself starting a line with one of those, though. Can you think of a scenario where this would happen?

Comment: @Forivin [`\`…\`.split(…)` has happened](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42034763/1048572). Also [IIFEs sometimes start with `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13341698/1048572). And `/…/.exec(…).forEach(…)` isn't unbelievable either.