# Destructuring obects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, object-destructuring

```js
let a=1
let b = 44
const obj = {a: 2,b: 444,c: 4444}
({a, b}=obj )
console.log(a,b)
```

Why this is not working?

I cant mutate variable.can someone help me out here.This code is bugginng me since 3 days

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? / Shaer the expected and actual output.

Comment: `const obj = {a: 2,b: 444,c: 4444};` note the `;`

Comment: Your code is evaluated as `{...}({a, b}=obj)`, because you're omitting the semicolons.

Comment: Relying on ASI isn't great, but maybe you could put another new line in-between `}` and `(`? (Edit: no, don't do this )

Comment: @deceze - I don't think it's the semmi colons that's the issue, the assignment is also wrong.

Comment: @Lissy How so? It works as expected when adding a semicolon.

Comment: @evolutionxbox More whitespace doesn't change anything.

Comment: @deceze _moar_ whitespace!!

Comment: @evolutionxbox [*Baybeh!*](https://youtu.be/tPh7OZew5oo)

Comment: @deceze  thanks for pointing out. i thought asi does the that work for me.

Comment: This is precisely why you shouldn't rely on ASI: because you probably won't remember when it will or won't ISA.

Comment: @deceze There is a [rather simple rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42034816/1048572) for where to put semicolons if you don't want them at the end of each line, but yeah one needs to know that rule and not just think "oh it's alright if I don't write any".