# Nested template string error in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does the following line result in a run-time error in Node.js?

`````
var a = ````;
`````

throws:

> TypeError: "" is not a function

---

Tested with Node.js versions 4.x, 6.x, 8.x and 9.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First two backticks are empty string while the next two will act as [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which will invoke the function before it. As `""`(empty string) is not an invokable function, it throws an error.

[Backticks calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29660381/2025923)

To nest backticks in template literal, escape it by preceding it with forward slash

```
console.log(`\`\``);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have two template literals immediately next to each other without any kind of joining expression. The parser recognizes that as a tagged function call, like `` String.raw`stuff here` ``. The first ``` `` ``` is evaluated, results in `""`, and then the JavaScript engine tries to call that empty string as a function, passing in the processed template literal. Since the empty string isn't a function, you get an error.

You get the same error more directly using ``` ""`` ```. :-)