# Backtick syntax function invocation in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example, we have code:

```
const a = '123'.split('').reverse().join('_');
```

We can do the same, if we write:

```
const a = '123'.split``.reverse().join`_`;
```

I want to find out when this feature appeared?

With ES6 string templates or other?

Does it work in all modern browsers? (I know it works in chrome)

Can not find anything, because the feature is exotic or a trick.

Please help.

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660381/backticks-calling-a-function

Comment: it part of the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) API.