# Advanced template string splitting

Tags: javascript, tagged-templates

I just found this really cool way to split a string, but I'm not sure why it works can anyone please explain it to me. .split`` instead of .split("")

```js
let str = "Justin"
console.log(str.split``) 
// ["J", "u", "s", "t", "i", "n"]
```

Comment: Tagged templates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backticks calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660381/backticks-calling-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let str = "Justin"
console.log(str.split``)
```

is a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates), which is equivalent to:

```js
let str = "Justin"
const strings = Object.freeze(Object.assign([""], { raw: [""] }))
console.log(str.split(strings))
```

This works because [`String.prototype.split(separator[, limit])`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.split) will convert the `separator` to a string in §21.1.3.21 step 7 if it doesn't implement the [`Symbol.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/split) method (checked in step 2), and `[""].toString() === ""`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a result of [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates), `str.split` is treated as a tag of the template (``` `` ```), and thus is called with the empty string as its first argument.