# what is the usage of backtick ` other than string interpolation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I just came into this code (styled-components library)

```
const Button = styled.button`
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  color: palevioletred;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
`
```

it seems that `styled.button` is a function but what is the use of the backtick here?

Comment: Easy way to make multi-line string constants. Also using a backtick string with a function like that *calls* the function.

Comment: It's a tagged template. `\`` defines a template and `styled.buttons` modifies it.

Comment: the return value is react component

Comment: That's a *really confusing way* of using a tagged template literal instead of a plain function call. Not recommended since it's so confusing, better to just call the function normally. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993999

Comment: @CertainPerformance Looking at the [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics) documentation it seems to be their recommended syntax

Comment: Ew. That's unfortunate.