# How is this string as a function argument working (no parentheses?!)?

Tags: javascript

Is this a new way to call a function? Whats this even called? Why do this?

```
const foo = a => console.log(a)

const k = foo`stuff here?` //whaaaaaaa

//output is ["stuff here?"]
```

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates. I too saw this syntax a while ago and didnt understand and after some searching found this.

Comment: I don't know who would downvote this. This isn't quite template literals, and even though I use it every week I don't actually know what it's called. It's a common pattern used in Styled-Components and Emotion.

Comment: I guess the name is "Tagged templates" as per Gowtham's link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backticks calling a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660381/backticks-calling-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are called tagged template functions. You can read more on how they work and what they do here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)